# Printing lines from one file if part of them appears in another. Both files are millions of lines long

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have two files, let's call them `123.txt` and `789.txt`. `123.txt` is 2.5M lines long, and `789.txt` is 65M lines long. Is there any way to use `grep` or similar to keep any lines from `789.txt` that contain lines from `123.txt?`

There will be a max of one duplicate per line in `789.txt`, and the duplicate text will be at the beginning of the line. I'm totally stuck on this, and couldn't find any info online, so I don't really have anything to start with. It will be running on a server, so I don't mind it taking a while (which I know it will)

- 123.txt:

  ```
  hxxp://www.a.com
  hxxp://www.b.com
  hxxp://www.c.com
  ```
- 789.txt:

  ```
  hxxp://www.a.com/kgjdk-jgjg/
  hxxp://www.b.com/gsjahk123/
  hxxp://www.c.com/abc.txt
  hxxp://www.d.com/sahgsj/
  ```
- Desired output:

  ```
  hxxp://www.a.com/kgjdk-jgjg/
  hxxp://www.b.com/gsjahk123/
  hxxp://www.c.com/abc.txt
  ```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this very easily using `grep`:

```
$ grep -Ff 123.txt 789.txt
http://www.a.com/kgjdk-jgjg/ 
http://www.b.com/gsjahk123/ 
http://www.c.com/abc.txt
```

The command above will print all lines from file `789.txt` that contain any of the lines from `123.txt`. The -f means "read the patterns to search from this file" and the -F tells grep to treat the search patterns as strings and not its default regular expressions.

This will not work if the lines of `123.txt` contain trailing spaces, `grep` will treat the spaces as part of the pattern to look for an will not match if it occurs within a word. For example, the pattern `foo`  (note the trailing space) will not match `foobar`.  To remove trailing spaces from your file, run this command:

```
$ sed 's/ *$//' 123.txt > new_file
```

Then use the `new_file` to grep:

```
$ grep -Ff new_file 789.txt
```

You can also do this without a new file, using the `i` flag:

```
$ sed -i.bak 's/ *$//' 123.txt
```

This will change file `123.txt` and keep a copy of the original called `123.txt.bak`.

(Note that this form of the `-i` flag to `sed` assumes you have GNU `sed`; for BSD `sed` use `-i .bak` with a space in between.)

Comment: I don't think the first option would work, regardless of the OP's case: it would print lines in `123.txt` that aren't in `789.txt` as well as lines in `789.txt` that appear in `123.txt` (they will only be printed once, but printed nonetheless).

Comment: @JosephR. you're absolutely right, my bad. I removed that suggestion. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Hi there, thanks very much :) it's almost working, but there are two small things - it should be keeping the ones that match the other file, and the partial match for the perl doesn't seem to be quite working in a test I ran, it seems to be because all my lines don't have any spaces in them. I'm sorry for the noobishness, my perl skills aren't very good.

Comment: @Joe not a problem. Could you add some example input to your question so I can get a better idea of what you need? Also include your desired output.

Comment: Hi there, thanks very much, that's almost working for me, however I only seem to be getting full matches rather than partial matches.

Comment: @Joe Make sure there are no spaces at the end of the lines of `123.txt`. A space will be considered as part of the pattern so `grep` will not match. To remove spaces from the ends of the lines of file `123.txt` run this: `sed 's/ *$//' 123.txt > new_file.txt`.

Comment: Aha, works perfectly! Thanks so so much for your help and all the time you put in :)

Answer (score 4):

If the files like in your example are sorted and always follow that pattern, you could write it:

```
join -t/ -1 3 -2 3 123.txt 789.txt |
  sed -n 's,\([^/]*/\)\([^/]*://\)\2,\2\1,p'
```

That would be the most efficient.