# How to remove lines included in one file from another file?

Tags: text-processing

I have two lists, a complete list and a partial list. I want a bash script that will search the complete list for any lines that are in the partial, if there are, they will be removed from the complete list. Can anyone help?

Comment: Possibly related: [Printing lines from one file if part of them appears in another. Both files are millions of lines long](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85211/printing-lines-from-one-file-if-part-of-them-appears-in-another-both-files-are)

Answer (score 25):

`grep` can read multiple patterns from a file, one per line. Combine with the options `-v` to output non-matching lines, and `-F` to match strings instead of regex and `-x` to require that the whole line matches.

```
grep -Fvx -f partial.list complete.list >remaining.list &&
mv remaining.list complete.list
```

Obviously the second command line is only if you want to overwrite the file containing the complete list.

If the partial list is huge and you don't mind reordering the list, then [`join`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85460/how-to-remove-lines-included-in-one-file-from-another-file-in-bash/85462#85462) may be faster.

Comment: this is great is you don't want to sort

Answer (score 15):

you can also use -

```
comm -23 file1 file2
```

the files have to be sorted for the command to work properly.
the entries from file2 will be removed from file1 in the output of the command

Comment: +1 for using `comm`. I really like the approach using `comm` I made it using grep but comm is nice for comparing files in all directions.

Answer (score 9):

If neither list has repeated elements, then the following will work:

```
join -t$'\n' -v1 <(sort complete) <(sort partial)
```

If the lists can contain repeated elements, and you just want to ignore repeats, you can use the `-u` flag in the sort subcommands, which will only output unique elements.